# Mellanox Drivers Need Contract?

Tags: infiniband, mellanox

I have a small Mellanox SAN for an ESXi lab. I've been running ESXi 5.1 on it, so I decided to experiment with 5.5 and 6.0 to get experience. When I went to the drivers at http://www.mellanox.com/page/products_dyn?product_family=36 it said:

> NOTE: To obtain the driver for ESXi 5.X v1.8.2.4, please contact
>   support@mellanox.com.

So, I contacted support, and got this reply:

> According to our records, we could not locate any valid contract for
>   you.

How does one get the drivers legitimately without a support contract for noncommercial purposes?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a licensing problem and requests help obtaining unlicensed software.

Comment: I'm not requesting unlicensed software, I'm asking if there is a legitimate means by which the drivers may be obtained so as to preserve my investment in my noncommercial lab.

Comment: Still completely off-topic here.

Answer (score 0):

I contacted Mellanox support and told them that I needed the drivers for my lab and noncommercial use. They were kind enough to provide me with a download link.